# jQuery range slider with two handlers. Reading min and max values values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI range slider and I have two hidden inputs to store the minimum and maximum values of the slider so as to later use them for a PHP query. But what happens is that my min and max value variables don't store the actual values but the ones before them. So there will be a +-1 variation respect to the real value. I guess I have to find a way to update the values before submitting the form. The code I am using is

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        values: [ 1, 10 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#minvalue").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
            $("#maxvalue").val( $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
            $("#amount").val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]);          
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val( $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
        " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));    
});
</script>

    <input type="hidden" id="minvalue" name="minvalue" />
    <input type="hidden" id="maxvalue" name="maxvalue" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here try this:

```
$(function() {

$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    values: [0, 11],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#minvalue").val(ui.values[0]);
        $("#maxvalue").val(ui.values[1]);
        $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
    }
});
$("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

});​
```

Comment: That doesnt work because you cant actually know where the slider button was before going to the last value. i dont know if you get my point but lets say i am having fun sliding the button up and down. Lets say i want to select the value 5 before going there i could be either in 6 or in 4.

Comment: isn't this a "snap to increments" slider?

Comment: No the increments arent visible if thats what you are asking.The whole script is what you see in my post

Comment: @tpaksu: OP is trying to tell you that values are not *selected-1* but rather previous selection... So if you selected 50 and then went to 4, hidden field would read 50... Then move it again to 35, hidden would read 4. Get it?

Comment: For some reason now the slider isnt visible..wait a minute to try and see what went wrong and i will answer you asap

Comment: For some strange reason with deleting the create: function(event, ui) {
            $("#minvalue").val(1);
            $("#maxvalue").val(10);
        } and worked just fine.Thank you so much!!

Comment: If you want post the whole answer so i can vote for your answer